# Scala populate map with random values

Tags: scala

I need to create a test for various collections based on Map and HashMap.

I have two functions that create test data, e.g.:

```
def f1: String = { ... )
def f2: String = { ... }
```

these functions create random data every time they are called.

My map is:

```
val m:Map[String,String] = ...
```

what I try to accomplish is construct an immutable map with 10000 random items that were generated by calling f1/f2. so protocode would be:

```
for 1 to 10000
   add-key-value-to-map (key = f1(), value = f2() )
end for
```

how can I accomplish this in scala, without destroying and rebuilding the list 10000 times?

EDIT:
Since it wasn't clear in the original post above, I am trying to run this with various types of maps (Map, HashMap, TreeMap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val m = (1 to 10000).foldLeft(Map.empty[String,String]) { (m, _) => m + (f1 -> f2) }
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up accepting this answer. The other answers were also valid, but they need more work to work with HashMap and TreeMap.

Comment: I did mention HashMap in the question, but it was probably not clear enough. I agree, my bad. As I said, none of the answers are wrong, this one is just generic enough to cover HashMap/TreeMap.

Comment: (to original commentor: you didn't have to delete your comment, I feel like I'm talking to myself now :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `List.fill` to create a List of couple `(String, String)` and then call `.toMap` on it:

```
scala> def f1 = util.Random.alphanumeric take 5 mkString
f1: String

scala> def f2 = util.Random.alphanumeric take 5 mkString
f2: String

scala> val m = List.fill(5)(f1 -> f2).toMap
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] =
     Map(T7hD8 -> BpAa1, uVpno -> 6sMjc, wdaRP -> XSC1V, ZGlC0 -> aTwBo, SjfOr -> hdzIN)
```

---

Alternatively you could use `Map`/`HashMap`/`TreeMap`'s `.apply` function:

```
scala> val m = collection.immutable.TreeMap(List.fill(5)(f1 -> f2) : _*)
m: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[String,String] = 
     Map(3cieU -> iy0KV, 8oUb1 -> YY6NC, 95ol4 -> Sf9qp, GhXWX -> 8U8wt, ZD8Px -> STMOC)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List.fill(10000)((f1, f2)).toMap
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tabulate` as follows,

```
Seq.tabulate(10000)(_ => f1 -> f2).toMap
```

It proves unclear whether the random key generator function may duplicate some keys, in which case `10000` iterations would not suffice to produce a map of such size.

An intuitive approach,

```
(1 to 10000).map(_ => f1 -> f2).toMap
```

Using a recursive function instead of generating a range to iterate over, (although numerous intermediate Maps are created),

```
def g(i: Int): Map[String,String] = {
  if (i<=0) 
    Map() 
  else 
    Map(f1 -> f2) ++ g(i-1)
}
```